# corARMA specification in a date*DayNight model

Tags: r, arma, lme4-nlme

I'm working on a model of animal movement speed as a function of date and day/night. For each animal (50 individuals), I have 2 values for each date an animal was present - a day value and a night value. I'm running a `lme()` model, trying to correctly specify the temporal autocorrelation. The sin and cos of the model's fixed parameters are a function of date:

```
df$sin <- sin(2*pi*as.numeric(df$Date)/365) # period= 365 days
df$cos <- cos(2*pi*as.numeric(df$Date)/365) # period= 365 days
```

This runs, but I'm guessing that the structure is incorrect

```
mod1 <- lme(log10(MeanSpeed) ~ Date*Light + sin + cos, 
   random= list(Tag = pdDiag(~ Light)), data=df,
   correlation=corARMA(0.3, p = 1, q =0))
```

A structure of `corARMA(form = ~Date, p = 1, q =0))` gives me the error `covariate must have unique values within groups for "corARMA" objects`, but (obviously?) runs when I restrict the dataset to either "Day" or "Night" cases only. How do I add the day/night variable into the correlation structure, if I want to run the dataset as a single model?

Thanks!

Comment: You should specify a time covariate in `corARMA`. Possibly `form = ~ Date |Light` or (more likely) something similar to `form = ~ (Date + (Light == "night") * 0.5)`.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Does this not restrict Light to be 'night' only in the syntax you suggest? Sorry for being dense...

Comment: No, this assigns Date values to the day and (Date + 0.5) to the night. You might have to do this by creating a new variable outside of `lme`. I can't test because you don't provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Ah, I think I'm starting to see the light (pun unintended). One more question - the way I'm envisioning it, the night-time and day-time autocorrelations should be separate (but similar), so that night-time and day-time trends are basically parallel. Will this achieve it? Basically, I want a correlation between day 1 and day 2, day 2 and day 3, etc, and between night 1 and night 2.... Or does it simply assess the correlation between day 1 and night 1, then night 1 and day 2, and so on?

Comment: That's the first example I gave: `form = ~ Date |Light` will use separate autocorrelation models for night and day. I'm just not really sure if that's reasonable. I think I might prefer one model and increase `p` (or `q`).

Comment: I'm thinking of sticking with `Date|Light`, especially that some of the models are looking at monthly information (while still comparing night/day). Plus, 'night' refers to dark (so both early morning and late evening), which means that having day as 0.5 is misleading. However, I'm getting an error message: `incompatible formulas for groups in 'random' and 'correlation'` since it apparently needs the grouping variables in both correlation and random var to be the same? (http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/lme-correlationstructure-AR1-and-random-factor-td3416248.html)